# Scala Play JDBC Insert with Map

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In the following code ... (taken from [Scala Play Tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaTodoList))

```
object Task {

val task = {
    get[Long]("id") ~
    get[String]("label") map {
        case id~label => Task(id, label)
    }
}

    ...

    def create(label:String) {
        DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
            SQL("insert into task (label) values ({label})").on(
                'label -> label
            ).executeUpdate()
        }
    }
```

Does the `'label -> label` mean insert the `map { id : label }` ?

I suppose the purpose is to write more concise code?

Answer (score 0):

`"insert into task (label) values ({label})"` is a template, `on` is rendering that template with a map of params of type `Symbol -> String`, and probably also sql escaping the params as it renders them. A symbol is basically just a type like a string which is optimized for being a key in a map.

Comment: so the benefit is concision since you only need to say "insert this key and you'll get the value inserted for free too?"

Comment: I would say `id` is autoincrement field in a `task`?

Comment: @idonnie - yes it is. it's a sequence, which I believe is an autoincremented field?

Answer (score 0):

`'label -> label` means `label:String` instead of `"{label}"`, because SQL syntax is `insert into table (field1, field2, ...) values (value1, value2, ...)`. Please read something about SQL, its a decent family of languages